# Sorting node graph by connections

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a node graph something like in the image below

[image]

I would like to sort the nodes by levels. So something like

```
[8, 4, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2, 7 , 6, 10]
```

When I construct the nodes and connections they can be in any order. like

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class ElementConnection:
    def __init__(self, element_source, element_dest):
        self.element_source = element_source
        self.element_dest = element_dest



element5 = Element("Element5")
element3 = Element("Element3")
element1 = Element("Element1")
element2 = Element("Element2")
element8 = Element("Element8")
element9 = Element("Element9")
element7 = Element("Element7")
element4 = Element("Element4")
element10 = Element("Element10")

elements = [element5, element3, element1, element2, element8, element10, element9, element7, element4]

connections = [
                ElementConnection(element8, element5),
                ElementConnection(element4, element3),
                ElementConnection(element9, element2),
                ElementConnection(element9, element7),
                ElementConnection(element5, element7),
                ElementConnection(element4, element9),
                ElementConnection(element2, element6),
                ElementConnection(element3, element1),
                ElementConnection(element6, element10),
                ElementConnection(element1, element10),
              ]
```

So I would like to sort the element list using the connection list.
Is there a standard way of achieving this ?

Thanks

Comment: What you describe is [*topological ordering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn.27s_algorithm).

Comment: If this isn't a learning exercise, I'd suggest investigating the NetworkX library rather than reinventing the wheel. See its documentation for [topological sort](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html), for example.

Comment: It's not a learning exercise. I was manly unaware of the names of the algorithm. My main code is in Rust but I have simplified it to experiment in Python.

Comment: can it be an acyclic graph or not?

Comment: I believe if I understand correctly it is a Directed acyclic graph. A nodes outputs can't loop around to its ancestors.
I am having trouble with the Breadth First Search algorithm as I don't necessarily have one root node. The image above is meant to been seen as going from left to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may consider [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm for a graph. It is not about any type of "sorting", but you can obtain required slices.
You can get description of this algotithm by the link above (it is an example for tree).

Comment: Accepted this as it seems to work well and was the first answer just for breadth first search.